# How to check whether a binary tree has the heap property?

Tags: haskell

Given a binary tree, I want to check whether it has the heap property e.g. if B is a child node of A then key(A)>=key(B):

`data Tree a = Leaf|Node a (Tree a)(Tree a)`

I have started my function as follows:

`isHeap :: Tree a -> Bool`

`isHeap Leaf = True`

`isHeap (Node a left right) = if (Node a)>= isHeap(left) && (Node a)>= isHeap(right) then True else False`

This is wrong as GHCI is telling that it couldn't match expected type Tree a->Tree a->Tree a with actual type Bool?

I know I am going wrong, but I think it is on the right tracks. Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: If you ever find yourself writing `if Condition then True else False` or `if Condition then False else True`, you can instead write simply `Condition` or `not Condition`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems.
Firstly, to use `>=` you need to add the `Ord` constraint, so the type of `isHeap` should be

```
isHeap :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
```

secondly, as well as knowing if child nodes satisfy the heap property, you also need the values of the child nodes. You can match on the child node types e.g.

```
isHeap :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isHeap Leaf = True

isHeap (Node a Leaf Leaf) = True
isHeap (Node a c1@(Node b _ _) Leaf) = ...
isHeap (Node a Leaf c2@(Node b _ _)) = ...
isHeap (Node a c1@(Node b _ _) c2@(Node c _ _)) = ...
```

in the last pattern, `b` and `c` are the values of the child nodes, which you will need to compare to the value of the parent (`a`), while `c1` and `c2` are the nodes themselves.

To answer the question about your error, the `Node` constructor is a function of type

```
Node :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

so the expression `(Node a)` is a function of type `Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a`. When you have

`if (Node a) >= isHeap(left)`

since `isHeap left` has type `Bool`, the compiler also expects the left-hand-side of `>=` to have the same type. However the reason you're having problems with writing that clause is that you don't have the value of the child nodes to compare with those of the parent.